# problem regarding crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Actually when I drag fields from a database onto a report and when I run the report, only the first row data is shown i.e. if CourseID field is dragged onto a report and when I run it should show CourseID1 and below it CourseID2. But, it shows only CourseID1. I know it is a silly thing, but as I'm new to crystal reports, I'm unable to solve it. So, please help me out...thanks in advance...

Comment: On the bottom, right hand side in the preview, you can see how many records Crystal receives.  How many does it show?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot? That would speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are dragging the field into the Details section of the report.  If it is in the header or other section, you may get only the first row.

Comment: Ya I did drag the field into the details section and it does show the next row, but it repeats whatever is there in the details section and then in that repetition it shows the next row. I want that CourseID2 should come below CourseID1 and even the design in the details section should not be repeated.

Comment: So what you want is two DB columns vertically stacked in the details section?  Perhaps you should add a second details section.  The two will be separated/delimited. Then place CourseID2 in the lower Details block.  Right-click in the left on Details and "Insert Section Below"

Comment: No. I don't want exactly two DB columns. It may vary

Comment: If the number of columns is variable, you can insert each column in its own Details section as described above, and then display the section only when nonempty.  In the Section Expert dialog, each section should have an option to "Suppress Blank Section" and I believe you can also create a formula to suppress them conditionally/programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first make a table on the report, then drag the desired fields into the table headers.

Comment: how to make the table on the report??

Comment: Sorry I was thinking SSRS, not Crystal.  If you drag the fields into the 'Details' section of the report the results should flow.

Comment: Ya I did drag the field into the details section and it does show the next row, but it repeats whatever is there in the details section and then in that repetition it shows the next row. I want that CourseID2 should come below CourseID1 and even the design in the details section should not be repeated.